# Is this approach using a dynamic array structure in C OK?

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I am just a beginner in C looking for a dynamic array structure and came across this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1Ge86RQBRs).

The [Code](http://bluefever.net/Downloads/BeginC/ch42.c) uses pointers to create a dynamic array without using heap memory allocation like malloc(). I just wonder, if this approach is Ok or it will likely become a bug, because memory can be overwritten?

The Code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct S_RacingCar {

    char name[8];
    int speed;

} RacingCar;

const int MaxCars = 4;

void PrintList() {
    printf("List Print...\n");
}

int AddCar(RacingCar *car) {
    printf("Enter Name And Speed: ");
    char input[16];
    fgets( input, 15, stdin);
    int ok = 0;

    int res = sscanf(input, "%s %d", car->name, &car->speed);

    if(res == 2) {
        ok = 1;
        printf("Added:%s Speed:%d\n\n",car->name,car->speed);
    } else {
        printf("Sorry, error parsing input\n\n");
    }
    return ok;
}

int main() {    

    RacingCar allCars[MaxCars];
    int numCars = 0;

    char command[16];
    char input[16];

    while( fgets( input, 15, stdin) ) {

        sscanf(input,"%s",command); 

        if ( strncmp(command, "quit", 4) == 0) {
            printf("\n\nBreaking...\n");
            break;      
        } else if ( strncmp(command, "print", 5) == 0) {
            PrintList();
        } else if ( strncmp(command, "add", 3) == 0) {
            if(numCars < MaxCars) {
                numCars += AddCar( &allCars[numCars] );
            } else {
                printf("Sorry List Is Full!!\n\n");
            }
        }
    }


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question.

Comment: The code you link to don''t create a dynamic array, it's a simple [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and it's fixed in size like any other array.

Comment: Read wikipage on [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)), and improve your code to get no warnings ....

Comment: ... then [debug with `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Hence, understand the behavior (probably wrong) of your program. Think. Correct your source code and repeat all till satisfied.

Comment: Don't forget to read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of every standard function you are using. Notably [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and [calloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) (and all the others from your code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no dynamic array in your code

```
RacingCar allCars[MaxCars];
```

Here, the max size of array is already defined as `MaxCars`. The thing that might seem to confuse you is that from `main` the reference to the array is sent to other functions where the value is being added into the array.
To create a dynamic array in C, you use `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` .